# Java String Input Buffer

Tags: java, io

While reading from the buffer , 
eg.

```
`Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
int variable = scan.nextInt();
double varDouble = scan.nextDouble();
String s = scan.nextLine();
// if this string has been entered just after an integer is entered, it 
//just shows empty output , might be a buffer clearing or something .
```

`
how the input is stored in the buffer ? 
how can the input buffer be cleared and what is the need?

Comment: _if this string has been entered just after an integer is entered_ Are you pressing the enter key twice ?

Comment: The default delimiter is `\p{javaWhitespace}+` Try `Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\n")`

Answer (score 0):

In `Scanner` class if we call `nextLine()` method after any one of the seven `nextXXX()` method then the `nextLine()` doesn’t not read values from console and cursor will not come into console it will skip that step. The `nextXXX()` methods are `nextInt()`, `nextFloat()`, `nextByte(`), `nextShort()`, `nextDouble()`, `nextLong()`, `next()`.

Thats because the [`Scanner#nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) method does not consume the last newline character of your input, and thus that newline is consumed in the next call to [`Scanner#nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()).

You can fire a blank [`Scanner#nextLine`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()) call after [`Scanner#nextInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) to consume rest of that line including newline